# ObjectDataSource methods can't refernce master page methods

Tags: asp.net, master-pages

So I have ObjectDataSource that has an update and delete method associated with it and the DS is conntected to a gridview.  When I call the methods, I want to repopulate a dropdown in the Master page that contains the same data as the grid, So i am trying to call the methods as follows:

```
            MyApp MasterPage = (MyApp)Page.Master;
            MasterPage.getData();
```

Now, if I do an insert from the grid (which is handled by the RowCommand event and not the DS) this works just fine, but thru the DS i get the following error: "Object reference not set to an instance of an object."

I can see certain fields on the aspx not being available yet from a postback, but how could a master page not be available to a page that is dependent on it?  Shouldn't i be able to reference it?  is there some backdoor trick to this?  I know I could get rid of the DS, but I want to use it cause it makes paging and sorting so easy.

Thanks

Comment: Have you put a breakpoint before `MasterPage.getData()` to verify that MasterPage is null? If you do that and find that it's not null, you can step into `getData()` and see if the null reference is in there.

Comment: When I dug into this a little more, it is calling the method, but since the method references a dropdown box (which doesn't exists yet) its bailing out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the order of events in the [masterpage-contentpage life-cycle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dct97kc3.aspx). You might be able to move your code to an event that fires after the master page has access to the dropdown box.

---

EDIT: an alternative

If you can't move the code, try to store the data in a property of the master page, then, once the dropdown has been initialised, go back to the master page and get the data.

```
protected object SomePropertyICreatedToStoreData {get;set;}

void GetData()
{
    // get the data (this part works already)
    var theData = WhereTheDataComesFrom

    // bind to dropdownlist - doesn't work, so...
    this.SomePropertyICreatedToStoreData = theData;
}
```

... then later

```
     this.MyDropDownList.DataSource = this.SomePropertyICreatedToStoreData;
```

Comment: Yeah, I could move to the rowCommand, but then ObjectDataSource will take offense, and I would really hate to have to write all the code is so nicely handles for me.

Comment: @Limey, the alternative I just added might work. If not, perhaps you could update the question showing the sequence of events you have and what isn't working.

Comment: Its not the data that is the issue, its adding the data to the object.  the method calls back to the dataset just fine, but when I try to bind that data to a dropdown list existing in the master page, it has then not yet been initialised.

Comment: Yeah, so once you have the data, store it so you can bind it later in the lifecycle (I added code above.)

Comment: I will have to give this a try.  for right now I am using a cheap work around, I just force the page to refresh when one on these values is added. I know that sounds bad, but the this is part or and adminstration screen, and a new value might be added once every couple of months.  I do, however, have other spots where i thinks this will be effective, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the Master directive:

```
<%@ MasterType TypeName ="MasterPageClassName" %>
```

or

```
<%@ MasterType virtualpath="~/Masters/Master1.master" %>
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xxwa0ff0.aspx

**Update:**  Separated TypeName and virtualpath as pointed out in the comments.

Comment: Same problem.  Seems to be just a different way to do the same action as I have above.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you need the reference. Try: <%@ MasterType TypeName ="MasterPageClassName" %>

Comment: same issue as before.  and you can have TypeName OR virtualpath, it won't let you have both.

Comment: mm... yeah I have TypeName on my class. Thanks for clarifying.